# C represent a UTF-8 multichar

Tags: c, utf-8

I am trying to store the block character (█, U+2588) in a char variable.

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {
  char block = '█';
  printf("Without storage: █\n");
  printf("With storage: %c\n", block);
}
```

But it gives me the warning

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:4:20: warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
       char block = '█';
                    ^~~~~
main.c:4:20: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]
```

The code outputs:

```
Without storage: █
With storage: �
```

The 'with storage' unknown is probably due to the char overflowing and only representing half of the character.

I am aware that the block character could be a UTF-8 multichar, so how might someone represent a UTF-8 multichar without any warnings?

Comment: Use a string instead of a char.

Comment: You can only store 1 byte in a 1 byte variable.  You need to use a string or a bigger integer type to store a multibyte UTF8 code point.

Comment: @HansPassant That doesn't seem to work, the code outputs `█�p@` instead. Used `char blockstr[3] = "█";`.

Comment: Why are you not using a `wchar`?

Comment: char[3] is not long enough to store that string, it is not zero-terminated.  U+2588 is encoded in utf8 as 0xe2, 0x96, 0x88.  You thus need a char[4].  Consider letting the compiler figure it out: char* blockstr = "█";

Comment: @HansPassant: or better: `char* blockstr = u8"█";` if using C11 or later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a wide character, hence a need for a different type. In this case `wchar_t` is the better choice, but that alone will not do it, you need to mark the constant itself as a wide character, too. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
int main()
{
   char c='A';
   wchar_t wc=L'█';

   printf("d%lcd d█d\n",wc); 
   puts("end");

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The marking for a wide charater constant is `L` (either single character or string) and to print it `%lc` and `%ls` respectively. But that alone didn't do it for me, the second `printf` still printed nothing. It was a problem of the console itself and setting locale helped (at least for me)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
   char c='A';
   wchar_t wc=L'█';
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
   printf("%c d█d\n",c);
   printf("d%lcd d█d\n",wc); 
   puts("end");

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```